# Manipulate ItemsSource but keep selected value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

In my application I have a `DataGrid` where the user can add rows by pressing a `Button`. By pressing the Button a new instance of `PlaceholderItem` will be added the `ObservableCollection<PlaceholderItem>` where the `DataGrid` is bound to.

The definition of the `DataGrid` in the View looks like:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PlaceholderItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          Background="White" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="70" MaxHeight="200" Margin="7,0"         > 
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Placeholder-Name" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox IsEditable="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AvailablePlaceholders, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="PlaceholderName"
                              Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxErrorTemplate}">
                        <ComboBox.Text>
                            <Binding Path="PlaceholderName" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    <local:PlaceholderValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue">
                                        <local:PlaceholderValidationRule.PlaceholderValidationRuleParamData>
                                            <local:PlaceholderValidationRuleParamData 
                                                UsedPlaceholders="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}, Path=Data.PlaceholderItems}"
                                                AvailablePlaceholders="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}, Path=Data.AvailablePlaceholders}"/>
                                        </local:PlaceholderValidationRule.PlaceholderValidationRuleParamData>
                                    </local:PlaceholderValidationRule>
                                </Binding.ValidationRules>
                            </Binding>
                        </ComboBox.Text>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Placeholder-Value" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource PlaceholderItemValueErrorTemplate}">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <Binding Path="PlaceholderValue" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                                <!--<Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    <local:PlaceholderValueValidationRule/>
                                </Binding.ValidationRules>-->
                            </Binding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>           
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

So the ItemsSource of the `DataGrid` is called PlaceholderItems. Each row of the `DataGrid` consists of two columns. First column is a `ComboBox` where the name of the `PlaceholderItem` will be selectable. And the second column is the value of the `PlaceholderItem`

The PlaceholderItem class has only two string-properties which implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

The `ComboBox` in the first column of each row is bound to an `ObservableCollection<PlaceholderItem>`. So the user can select an item from the `ComboBox` and the value of the `PlaceholderItem` will be written to the `TextBox` in the second column.

Therfor I'm using the following code in the ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<PlaceholderItem> PlaceholderItems
{
    get
    {
        if (placeholderItems == null)
        {
            placeholderItems = new ObservableCollection<PlaceholderItem>();
            placeholderItems.CollectionChanged += PlaceholderItemsOnCollectionChanged;
        }
        return placeholderItems;
    }
}



private void PlaceholderItemsOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach (PlaceholderItem placeholderItem in e.NewItems.OfType<PlaceholderItem>())
        {
            placeholderItem.PropertyChanged += PlaceholderItemOnPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach (PlaceholderItem placeholderItem in e.OldItems.OfType<PlaceholderItem>())
        {
            placeholderItem.PropertyChanged -= PlaceholderItemOnPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}

private void PlaceholderItemOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "PlaceholderName")
    {
        PlaceholderItem targetAvailablePlaceholderItem =
            AvailablePlaceholders.FirstOrDefault(p =>
                p.PlaceholderName == ((PlaceholderItem)sender).PlaceholderName);

        if (targetAvailablePlaceholderItem != null)
        {
            ((PlaceholderItem)sender).PlaceholderValue = targetAvailablePlaceholderItem.PlaceholderValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything just works fine.

The problem now:

If the user has added a new row and has selected an item from the `ComboBox` I want to remove the selected item from the AvailablePlaceholders-Collection. So that the user can't select it anymore it other rows.

I've tried the following in the PlaceholderItemOnProertyChanged-Method:

```
        if (e.PropertyName == "PlaceholderName")
        {
            PlaceholderItem targetAvailablePlaceholderItem =
                AvailablePlaceholders.FirstOrDefault(p =>
                    p.PlaceholderName == ((PlaceholderItem)sender).PlaceholderName);

            if (targetAvailablePlaceholderItem != null)
            {
                ((PlaceholderItem)sender).PlaceholderValue = targetAvailablePlaceholderItem.PlaceholderValue;

                AvailablePlaceholders.Remove(targetAvailablePlaceholderItem);

            }
            ((PlaceholderItem)sender).ForcePropertyChanged();
        }
```

The item is removed from the collection, but the value in the `ComboBox` is empty now.

Is there a possibility to remove an item from the ItemsSource of the ComboBox but the Text-Property of the ComboBox keeps the value?

Comment: The `ComboBox` can only select an item that is in the `ItemSource`. If value x is selected and you remove it from the source collection, what value do you expect to be selected?

Comment: I thought that binding the Text-Property would be keept. The user also can type in some custom value, which is not in the itemssource

Comment: The control tries to select an item in the `ItemsSource` based on the typed in value.

Comment: What's stopping them just typing the same name in two different rows? Are rows still editable after they have been added?

Comment: Yes, they are alway editable.